# How to ignore SVN folders in WinMerge?

Tags: svn, diff, winmerge

I'm trying to recursively compare two Subversion working copy folders using WinMerge.

Unfortunately, WinMerge displays lots of differencing files inside of the subversion control folders (`.svn` or `_svn`).

Is it possible to somehow exclude the subversion folders from the comparison?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## Try making a Filefilter

WinMerge handles this just fine.  You want to create and use a [**Filter**](http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html).  Under `Tools | Filters... | Filefilters`, create a new filter or modify an existing one.

It will look like this:

```
## Ignore Java class and jar files
f: \.class$
f: \.jar$

## Ignore subversion housekeeping directories
d: \\.svn$
d: \\._svn$
```

Save it, then when selecting items to merge, select the filter you defined from the `Select Files or Folders` dialog box. Bonus points: It will save this and use it as a default for future merges.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I discovered that there is even a predefined filter to exclude source control files and folders.

Comment: Hi Martin, you might want to accept 4h24d's answer as well since it is simpler than this and appropriate and thus has been voted better so far.

Comment: Better filter "\\\.svn$" (predefined filter) so you match '.' and not <any character> before 'svn'.

Answer (score 90):

## Try Builtin File Filter

WinMerge (Version 2.12.4) already includes a [filter](http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html) to exclude source control files and directories, and it's called **Exclude Source Control**.

It works for Subversion, CVS, Git, Bazaar and Mercurial, and it doesn't require you to create a filter, you just have to apply it during the comparison.

Comment: thanks for the information. i would like to avoid selecting everytime i compare. is there anyway we can make it apply "Exclude Source control" files by default?

Comment: I wasn't getting this option in a fresh install when I selected 2 folders and clicked 'Compare'. To enable it I had to select one folder, click 'Compare...' which shows a dialog with some options for filters. Here I selected the second folder and the 'Exclude Source Control' filter, and it worked. The filter is saved, so new if I just select 2 folders and click 'Compare' the filter is applied without the dialog.

Answer (score 26):

## Uncomment some lines in builtin filefilter

WinMerge (Version 2.12.4) already includes a filter but (at least in my installation) the filters for Subversion, Git and Bazaar were commented out.

Navigate here: `Tools | Filters | Filefilters | Exclude Source Control` (double click to edit)

Edit the lines to look like this:

```
d: \\.svn$ ## Subversion working copy
d: \\_svn$  ## Subversion working copy ASP.NET Hack
d: \\cvs$   ## CVS control directory
d: \\.git$ ## Git directory
d: \\.bzr$ ## Bazaar branch
d: \\.hg$ ## Mercurial repository
```

Comment: Better filter "\\\.svn$" (predefined filter) so you match '.' and not <any character> before 'svn'.

Answer (score 0):

n the latest versions you can specify on the `Select Files` dialog:

[image]

See https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/discussions/1571